# Difference between using "struct S" or "S" as typename

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, declaration

In the C language the name of a structured type `S` ist `struct S`.

In C++ one can also use `struct S` as typename instead of `S` as usual for

```
struct S {};

struct S s1; // also ok in C++
S s2; // normal way in C++
```

So, the assumption is, that using `struct S` or `S` as typename in C++ is a matter of taste ;-)

But in the following example there are places where `struct S` is not allowed:

```
struct S1 {
    S1(int x = 0) : x{x} {}
    int x{};
};

typedef S1 S2;

template<typename T>
auto foo(T a) {
//    T::_; // T is deduced to `S` in all cases
    return S1{a};
//    return struct S1{a}; // NOK
}

int main() {
//    foo(struct S1{i}); // NOK
    
    S1 s1;
    foo(s1);
    
    struct S1 s2{2};
    foo(s2);
    
    foo(1);

//    struct S2 s20; // NOK
    S2 s21;    
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what this unsymmetry is about?
It looks like `struct S` is not allowed where a ctor call as part of an expression is needed. But if a type `S` could also be written as `struct S` it should also be ok to use `struct S{}` as a ctor call.

Comment: the error messages hold lots of useful information. I suggest to focus on 1 maybe 2 cases and include the erroneous code and the error message in the question

Comment: The return statement will compile if you change it like `return (struct S1){a}:`. I believe the reason is the compiler can't tell if you're defining a scope-local `struct S1` or you refer to already existing `struct S1`.

Comment: The explanation is that the assumption is wrong. C++ does not do this to empower us with "stylistic choices". It does it primarily for C compatibility, and C doesn't have the expressions you ponder about.

Comment: *But if a type `S` could also be written as `struct S`...* The operative word is "could", and it cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the assumption is, that using `struct S` or `S` as typename in C++ is a matter of taste ;-)

The above assumption is wrong as there are exceptions to it(as also noted in your example) and the reason has more to do with C compatibility than a matter of taste.

**The point is that** there are rules for when we can/cannot use `struct S1` as a replacement for just `S1`. And assuming that we can always use `struct S1` as a replacement for `S1` is wrong.

---

The operand of the return statement should be an expression but `struct S1{a}` is not an expression and hence cannot be used in the return statement:

```
//-----vvvvvvvvvvvv----> operand is not an expression
return struct S1{a};
```

An expression involving `struct S1` would look something like:

```
return (struct S1)a;
```

---

There are also situation(s) when we need to use `struct S1` and using just `S1` won't work. A contrived example is given below:

```
struct S1 
{
    
};
int S1() 
{
    std::cout<<"function called"<<std::endl;
    return 5;
}

int main() 
{
     //S1 s; // ERROR: This won't work unless we use struct S1
     
     struct S1 s2; //WORKS
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Writing `struct S1 s1;` is allowed in C++ for one reason: compatibility with C. C allows you to have **at the same time** a function called `S1`, so `struct S1` is an explicit disambiguation. C++ also allows this, *for backwards compatibility only*.

However, in contexts where backwards compatibility is not applicable, C++ does not. C doesn't have constructors, for instance.

There's one other point of confusion in the question:

```
typedef S1 S2;
struct S2 s2;
```

`S2` is not a `struct` name but an alias name, and you can't prefix an alias name with `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

`class-key` class or struct are used only in declarations. Constructors and destructors are named as functions using `class-name`.

For example in this declaration

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
};
```

the constructor and destructor looks like function declarations that have no explicit return type.

Such a record

```
struct A
{
    struct A() = default;
    struct ~A() = default;
};
```

will be invalid. Encountering the keyword struct the compiler will consider these records as incorrect declarations.

I think that under the hood there is a desire to avoid  a possible ambiguity. For example this construction

```
struct A()
```

looks like a function type that has no parameters and has the return type struct A. Or this record

```
struct A {}
```

looks like a structure definition.

Pay attention to that using an elaborated name also introduces a new type in the given scope. Consider this code snippet

```
struct A {};

int main()
{
    struct A;

    struct A { int x; };
}
```

The record `struct A;` in main introduces a new type in the block scope of main that hides the structure with the same name introduced in the global namespace..